# Relation between attributes in related class

Tags: uml, uml-designer

It's possible to model the relation between attributes in associated class with the UML Designer? The objective is choose a source and the target class for describe one interaction between objects(for example describe a message in a sequence diagram) Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't know UML Designer. But the above is an invention by Sparx for EA. It's (IIRC) not really forbidden by the UML specs, but you will not see that notation anywhere else but in EA.

Comment: Ok, @ThomasKilian and how is suppose that must be designed the message exchange between two objects or instances(source to target) for example in a sequence diagram, following the UML specs?

Comment: It's open/undefined. You can invent your own notation. E.g. a stereotyped association with role names. The connectors you see are simple dependencies but can be regarded as stereotyped for the adornments on both ends. The fact that they are sticky is a tooling feature in EA.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to represent dependencies in UML designer directly from attributes to attributes.

Comment: I see, thanks, any other alternative that you know, instead of EA?